# Round the corners without changing the stroke's width?

Tags: inkscape, vector, shapes, corners

How do I round the corners on the 1st image without changing the stroke's width like it's done on the 2nd one?

Also I wonder whether I can change all the corners equally, so that they all have the same radiuses.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The [Corners (Fillet Chamfer) Path Effect](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/live-path-effects.html#examples) can do everything you want.

Comment: There's also a nice tutorial [on youtube for Inkscape 1.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXrzemHHQG0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The path in the left has only sharp corners. Its duplicate in the right has got path effect "corners". Every corner gets the same radius, but the corners can be adjusted with the node tool separately. The adjustments are possible also afterwards as long as the effect is not fixed.

It works as well if the path has a fill color:

[image]

And it works as well if the path has a fill color, but no stroke:

[image]

The effect can be removed, if wanted. But it can be fixed so that the path becomes like it's drawn manually to the wanted corner curvatures. The fixing: Apply Path > Object to Path. After it the corners have only ordinary Bezier curve nodes:

[image]

Effects should be fixed if you are going to use the path as SVG in some other software. Also applying more effects causes easily unexpected results if previous effects are not fixed. That's a difficult to avoid consequence of Inkscape's distributed development by volunteer programmers. But the program has got substantially better in the recent year. And in many cases inserting another effect works well.

Comment: Yes, this does work. I have done this shape by applying Union and Difference to 3 paths, and the issue now is that rounding corners also changes the path's filling. Do I have to edit my initial path just with Node tool to avoid this?
[my path](https://imgur.com/Q0nBzwl)

Comment: @IDBB Sorry, but I do not have a slightest idea how your linked path has got its fill. I added to my answer how the corner effect behaves when the fill color is selected in Fill & Stroke dialog. I have Inkscape 1.3 in Win10. Your result is totally unexpected. If it happened that you used the area fill tool (=Paint bucket) the result can be understood. It's on-the-screen bitmap image vectorizer and totally useless for accurate work. It does not insert a fill color, but generates a new shape by tracing your screen bitmap to vector.

Comment: I see, I guess I have just done something wrong before, so I created this shape once more and it works perfectly now. Thank you.